# Docker can't connect to adminer port

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, adminer

Hi i'm working with docker-compose file to work with postgresql and adminer(database interface).

I followed the instruction on the postgres image on docker hub and do docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml postgres_test, but when i try to connect to 45.77.46.240(my host machine ip):8282(adminer port) from another machine it response with a 'ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT'

I wonder why can i connect to the visualizer on port 8080 it worked but not on the adminer?

Here my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3"
services:
adminer:
   image: adminer
   restart: always
   ports:
     - "8282:8282"
db:
   image: postgres
   networks:
     - webnet
   environment:
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
     POSTGRES_USER: postgres
     POSTGRES_DB: real_estate
   volumes:
     - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
web:
   # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
   image: my_user_name/test_image:image1
   ports:
     - "8081:8081"
   networks:
     - webnet
   environment:
     DB_HOST: db
visualizer:
   image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
   volumes:
     - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
   deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
   networks:
     - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Comment: I think adminer by default uses 8080 inside the container, but you should be able to map that to the publicly exposed port 8282 with `8282:8080`. (see https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports)

Answer (score 3):

This is another answer to specific port on adminer docker

```
version: "3"
services:
adminer:
   image: adminer
   restart: always
   ports:
   - "8282:8282"
   command:
   - 'php'
   - '-S'
   - '[::]:8282'
   - '-t'
   - '/var/www/html'
   entrypoint:
   - 'entrypoint.sh'
   - 'docker-php-entrypoint'
```

Answer (score 2):

This not working due to the port issue. You have configured it as 8282. Adminer default port is 8080 and you can't change adminer default port. Therefore give try with the following code.

```
version: "3"
services:
adminer:
   image: adminer
   restart: always
   ports:
     - "8282:8080"
db:
   image: postgres
   networks:
     - webnet
   environment:
     POSTGRES_PASSWORD: 123
     POSTGRES_USER: postgres
     POSTGRES_DB: real_estate
   volumes:
     - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
web:
   # replace username/repo:tag with your name and image details
   image: my_user_name/test_image:image1
   ports:
     - "8081:8081"
   networks:
     - webnet
   environment:
     DB_HOST: db
visualizer:
   image: dockersamples/visualizer:stable
   ports:
     - "8080:8080"
   volumes:
     - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
   deploy:
      placement:
        constraints: [node.role == manager]
   networks:
     - webnet
networks:
  webnet:
```

Answer (score -2):

there are few options for the solution, anyhow the problem is not related to docker.

you should look at it as a process running in a machine over port 8282. It is accessible only to the host machine. It is not exposed to the world

the most straightforward solution is using ssh tunnel

https://www.ssh.com/ssh/tunneling/example

Comment: don't know why but when i change adminer port to 8080 it worked , but other ports doesn't seem to work.Also because i changed adminer to 8080 and changed visualizer to other ports now the visualizer doesn't work.Is port 8080 the only port that support interface ?

Comment: nope. all ports are working the same, just need to open them to be accessible out of the machine. if you have problems with ssh tunnelling, you can use tools like ngrok: https://ngrok.com/